# How to make PowerShell V2 Remoting work with Windows Server 2003?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003, powershell-remoting

I was testing PowerShell remoting:

1. I installed [PowerShell V2 CTP3](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=131969) on my Windows XP desktop
2. I installed [WS-Management v1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=845289ca-16cc-4c73-8934-dd46b5ed1d33&DisplayLang=en) on my Windows 2003 R2 server, which has its firewall disabled and no PowerShell installed.
3. Both machines have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

When I type on my desktop:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName computerNameHere Win32_Service
```

I got the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Access denied. (HRESULT exception: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

What else I have to do to get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Remoting. PowerShell Remoting is not supported on XP/2003, only Vista/2008 and up (though a WSMan update should be released for XP/2003 in the next few months).

Do you have admin priviligies on the remote box? If not, try with the credential parameter:

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName computerNameHere Win32_Service -Credential $cred

Comment: powershell remoting is supported on windows server 2003 now, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, powershell remoting is supported on windows server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

PSH V2 uses [WinRM 2.0](https://connect.microsoft.com/wsman) (*not 1.1*), and this is only available in its CTP form currently, and limited to Vista and 2008.

PSH team blog entries have mentioned (IIRC) this being a CTP limitation, but currently unclear how it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use another remoting solution like the /n software PowerShell Server:  www.nsoftware.com/powershell/

Answer (score 0):

The issue the user is having is not with PowerShell Remoting.  `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName computerNameHere` uses **WMI Remoting** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is more about wmi than powershell remoting, here is my experience with powershell remoting on a windows 2003 machine. It works fine with a admin user.
But while doing remoting with a non-admin user on 2003, you can run powershell cmdlets fine, but can't run any.

http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/16205.aspx